# Control Relay by MQTT Publish Subcribe

Tags: c++, mqtt, esp32, relay

sorry for my bad english, but i'll try my best

i have a code like this

```
void mqttCallback(char *topic, byte *payload, unsigned int length)
{
  Serial.print("Message arrived [");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print("] ");
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();
  if (strcmp(topic, DeviceConfig.MqttSub) == 0)
  {
    Serial.print("Recvd relay command parse code: ");
    StaticJsonDocument<100> doc;
    DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, (char *)payload);
    Serial.println(error.code());
    if (error == DeserializationError::Ok)
    {
      if (doc.containsKey("state") && doc["state"].is<int>())
      {
        DeviceConfig.RelayOn = (doc["state"].as<int>() == 1);
        Serial.print("Changing state: ");
        Serial.print(DeviceConfig.RelayOn );
        Serial.println();
      }
    }
  }
  
}
```

it means if the broker send data like {state : 1}, it automactically changing state turn on, or {state : 0} to turn off, it works if i see on serial monitor, the state status is changed, but the relay is not affected at all

this is the loop function

```
void loop()
{

  mqttReconnect();
  if (client.connected() && millis() - lastSendMs >= (DeviceConfig.MqttPubSec * 1000))
  {
    Serial.print("Publishing:");
    String json = composeSensorJson();
    Serial.println(json);
    Serial.println(client.publish(DeviceConfig.MqttPub, json.c_str()) ? "OK" : "FAIL");
    lastSendMs = millis();
  }
  if (DeviceConfig.Device == Relay) {
    digitalWrite(AIO_SENSOR_PIN_3, DeviceConfig.RelayOn ? LOW : HIGH);
  }
  client.loop();
}
```

why the relay is not working

---

this is the serial monitor if the state is 1
[image: state :1]

and this is the monitor if state is 0
[image: state:0]

Comment: does the relay work with a simple test sketch?

Comment: yes it work with a simple test sketch

Comment: add to question what is printed to Serial Monitor

Comment: yeah sure, posted it

Comment: there is ON/OFF and you have `doc["state"].as<int>() == 1`

Comment: yes, there is, it's changed the state on serial monitor, but not for the relay

Comment: `"ON"` is not equal to `1`